# AdWords Script Report - Export to sheet with impressions bigger than 0

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-ads-api

This would be my code. I'm wondering how with this method of reporting would I be able to set a rule that only exports the data with more than 0 impressions.

```
function main() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");

var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName( "Raw Monthly Data" );

var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT Date, AdGroupName, Clicks, Impressions, Conversions, Cost, ConversionRate, CostPerConversion, AverageCpc " +
   "FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " + "THIS_MONTH");

   report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `where Impressions > 0` condition in `select` query as below:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT Date, AdGroupName, Clicks, Impressions, Conversions, Cost, ConversionRate, CostPerConversion, AverageCpc " +
       "FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT where Impressions > 0 " + "THIS_MONTH");
```

Edit: I notice you have another issue, you're missign the word "DURING" before the date. That'll need fixing too.